# Generic Id property in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have existing solution, which uses code-first approach.
It has `PersistentEntity` as base class for all entities.

```
public interface IPersistentEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
    bool IsNew { get; }
}

public abstract class PersistentEntity : IPersistentEntity, IValidatableObject
{
    // some code here
}
```

`PersistentEntity` is used as validation object + overrides default behavior for `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. As soon as `Id` property is of type `int` -> `IsNew` property has simple implementation:

```
public bool IsNew
{
    get
    {
        return this.Id == 0;
    }
}
```

`IsNew` itself is used by generic repository `Repository`. And everything works ok.

But now we decided to use `Guid` as Id for one of our entities, which a bit breaks the design.
The first idea is to implement `PersistentEntity` in generic fashion -> `PersistentEntity<T>`, which is fine, but in that case it break the generic `Repository<T>`:

```
IEntityRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class, IPersistentEntity<??>
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does `IPersistentEntity` need to have an `Id` property on it? If yes, it seems like this change will break anything which uses that property; if no, you could just remove that property from the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only `IsNew` in `Repository<T>` method, you can separate the interface for that. Like

```
public interface IPersistentEntity 
{
    bool IsNew { get; } 
}

public interface IPersistentEntity<T> : IPersistentEntity
{
    T Id { get; }
}
```

So you can declare your method as

```
IEntityRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class, IPersistentEntity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass more than one Generic value like so:

```
Repository<T, TIdent>() where T : class, IPersistentEntity<TIdent>
```

and then your IPersistentEntity would look like this:

```
public interface IPersistentEntity<out TIdent>
{
    TIdent Id { get; }
    bool IsNew { get; }
}
```